# How can I return a boost::variant made from a subset of the types contained in boost::varaint return type

Tags: c++, boost, variant, boost-variant

I have 4 functions:

```
boost::variant<type1,type2,type3>processFile(const char* file){
     if(----expression that if true means I have to process as type 1----)
          return processType1(file);   //this just returns type1
     else if(----expression that if true means I have to process as either type 1 or type 2----)
           return processType23(file); //this returns boost::variant<type2,type3>. This also calls 2 more processing functions depending on type.
}
```

processType23 takes a script file which will determine which type gets sent back. I want to keep the determination of the type in this file. However I cannot return the boost::variant. I get the following error:

```
error: could not convert 'engine::fileManager::processLua(const char*)()' from 'boost::variant<engine::material, engine::shader>' to 'boost::variant<engine::material, engine::shader, unsigned int>'
```

What is the (proper) way to return the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a visitor:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/637a346d627e9202)</kbd>**

```
template <typename R, typename A> convert_variant(A const& arg) {
    return boost::apply_visitor([](auto const& v) -> R { return R{v}; }, arg);
}
```

### Update

In response to the observation made by @llonesmiz, you may wish to compile the conversion code even if some conversions might be illegal. In that case you will have to use some type traits to dinstinguish those cases and act accordingly:

### C++03 Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e76b5be36d98c885)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename R>
struct convert_variant_visitor : boost::static_visitor<R> {
    struct bad_conversion : std::runtime_error {
        bad_conversion(std::string msg) : std::runtime_error(msg) {}
    };

    template <typename T>
        typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_convertible<T, R>::value, R>::type
        operator()(T const& v) const 
    {
        return R(v); // or just v
    }

    template <typename T>
        typename boost::enable_if_c<not boost::is_convertible<T, R>::value, R>::type
        operator()(T const& v) const 
    {
        throw bad_conversion(std::string("Cannot convert ") + typeid(v).name() + " to " + typeid(R).name());
        //throw bad_conversion("Not convertible to variant");
    }
};

template <typename R, typename A> R convert_variant(A const& arg) {
    return boost::apply_visitor(convert_variant_visitor<R>(), arg);
}

int main() {
    typedef boost::variant<std::string, int, double> V1;
    typedef boost::variant<int, double> V2;
    V1 input = 42;
    V2 output = convert_variant<V2>(input);

    std::cout << "input:  " << input  << " (which: " << input.which()  << ")\n";
    std::cout << "output: " << output << " (which: " << output.which() << ")\n";
}
```

Prints

```
input:  42 (which: 1)
output: 42 (which: 0)
```

### C++17 Demo

Modern C++ features are making generic code like this much simpler:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/552b8ecc6648efb2)</kbd>**

```
template <typename R, typename A> R convert_variant(A const& arg) {
    return boost::apply_visitor([](auto const& v) -> R {
            if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<decltype(v), R>)
                return v;
            else
                throw std::runtime_error("bad conversion");
        } , arg);
}
```

Comment: Very nice, but I think that [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd18b43153f6f8c9) (that sadly fails) is something that is nearer to what the asker wants.

Comment: @llonesmiz you're quite right of course. Let me fix that. Back in 20 minutes

Comment: @llonesmiz I just updated the answer so that illegal conversions turn into runtime error. This make it work also in the case you highlight: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e76b5be36d98c885

Comment: And a [c++17 version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/552b8ecc6648efb2) just to show how much simpler that can be

Comment: [Just something to keep in mind](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1ca9a701ac3e716) although it should not be a problem given the cascade of `if`s actually do their work.

Comment: @llonesmiz Yeah. That's the caveat with variant in general. It's worse than this, and completely unrelated to this conversion task: [using boost variant](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b218027390239749) as well as [std::variant](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bbc375fdfb56046)

Comment: @sehe very nice answer but (since I am not very aquainted with boost yet) I have a few questions: 1. Is the very first version of the solution acceptable IF the function cannot produce a different type (without throwing an exception, which will terminate the function and be cought)? 2. ---snip--

Comment: The first version will simply not compile if any combination of source alternative and target variant does not have a suitable conversion. Which is usually what I'd design for

Comment: @sehe ok. Also I have another question. You solution implies that I know what the process function returned (it can either return type1 or type2). However I wanna pass EITHER of those down to the "lower layer" without having to explicitly convert to either one of them. Is this possible?

Comment: My code makes no such assumption anywhere. Also, variants by definition have a bounded list of alternative types. Look at `boost::any` for something more dynamic. Fair warning: I consider a using `boost::any` almost always a design flaw (exception: passing opaque types across language/module boundaries)

Comment: @sehe Sorry I know I must be hard to work with but I just dont get it yet :(. Lets say I have a function with a return type that is a variant of 3 types and I wanna return a variant of 2 types (which is a subset of the types of the 3 types in the return type, which means either way it is gonna be ONE of the types of the variant in the return type). This is what I tried to describe in my answer. How would I use your solution without knowing a explicit type? (sorry again I am not the best at this stuff.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158596/discussion-between-sehe-and-moustachespy).